# Simplification on the estimation on error of the ratio of 2 random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian, statistical-physics, taylor-series, expectation

Let $Z=\dfrac{X}{Y}$ the ratio of 2 random variables.

**Distribution of $Z=\dfrac{X}{Y}$**

Consider the case of two independent normal variables $X$ and $Y$ with strictly positive means and variances $\left(\mu_{x}, \sigma_{x}^{2}\right)$ and $\left(\mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}^{2}\right),$ respectively. The case where their coefficients of variation, $\delta_{x}=\sigma_{x} / \mu_{x}, \delta_{y}=\sigma_{y} / \mu_{y},$ are smaller than one will be considered here. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ depends only on four parameters $\left(\mu_{x}, \sigma_{x}, \mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}\right)$ in this case since the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is zero.

Therefore, the joint density of $Y$ and $Z=X / Y$ can be obtained from that of $X$ and $Y$, by the change of variable theorem, and it will depend as well on the same four parameters. Consider the following one to one convenient reparametrization,
$$
\left(\mu_{x}, \sigma_{x}, \mu_{y}, \sigma_{y}\right) \longleftrightarrow\left(\beta, \rho, \delta_{y}, \sigma_{x}\right)
$$
where $\beta=\mu_{x} / \mu_{y}, \rho=\sigma_{y} / \sigma_{x} .$ The joint density of $Y$ and $Z$ can be factored as
$$
f_{Y, Z}\left(y, z ; \beta, \rho, \delta_{y}, \sigma_{x}\right)=f_{Z}\left(z ; \beta, \rho, \delta_{y}\right) f_{Y \mid Z}\left(y \mid z ; \beta, \rho, \delta_{y}, \sigma_{x}\right)
$$

where $f_{Z}\left(z ; \beta, \rho, \delta_{y}\right)$ is the marginal density function of $Z$. This density $f_{Z}$ depends only on the three identifiable parameters $\left(\beta, \rho, \delta_{y}\right)$ and can be expressed as
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{Z}\left(z ; \beta, \rho, \delta_{y}\right)=& \frac{\rho}{\pi\left(1+\rho^{2} z^{2}\right)} \exp \left[-\frac{\left(\rho^{2} \beta^{2}+1\right)}{2 \delta_{y}^{2}}\right] \\
& \times\left\{1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} q \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{q}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \exp \left(\frac{q^{2}}{2}\right)\right\},
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
q=\frac{\left(1+\beta \rho^{2} z\right)}{\delta_{y} \sqrt{1+\rho^{2} z^{2}}}
$$

**QUESTION1 :** How could I exploit it in my case to extract the standard deviation or variance of this PDF ?

**QUESTION2 :** Can I take for correlation coefficient the correlation coeffcient computed from the fiducial values in a Fisher's formalism context (5 values different for ficucials). Indeed, the fiducial values in Fisher correspond rather to the mean for each variable, don't them ?

Comment: If you would know that X and Y are independent you might be able to do some simplifications.

Comment: At the beginning of this question you seem to use lower-case letters for random variables and capitals for the arguments to their density functions, in contrast to conventional usage, but later in the question you're using capitals to refer to the random variables.

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then $X/Y$ is Cauchy-distributed. In particular, $\operatorname{Var}(f(X,Y))$ is not defined in this event. You might find the results at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Normal_ratio_distributions useful though.

Comment: @SteveHunstman : thanks for the link but I don't know how to exploit the section concerned to comute the error on the ratio of 2 Normal Random Variables. I mention it in **EDIT2** above. If you had any idea ... Regards